# XWPFRuns and XWPFParagraph Apache POI помогите исправить

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

Добрый день, помогите исправить, суть такая есть исходный документ (шаблон) его нужно изменять, меняя часть шаблонного текста на нужную, но проблема в том, что

```
`for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            System.out.println("-----"+p.getText());
```

и

```
`for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);`
```

отличаются, т.е. runs разбивает входящую строку параграфа и не получается проверить на вхождение и заменить участок нужного теста. Пример кода

```
public static void ChengePattern(Paragraphs paragraphs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("fileName.docx"));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            //System.out.println("-----"+p.getText());
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
           if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    if (text != null && text.contains("Name")) {
                        text = text.replace("Name", paragraphs.address);
                        r.setText(text, 0);
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.contains("Address")) {
                        text = text.replace("Address", paragraphs.address);
                        r.setText(text, 0);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream("path\\output.docx"));
}
```

пробовал собирать runs стрингбилдером, и заменять в нем нужную часть текста и вставлять в Runs, но лучшее чего смог добиться это просто вставка нужного мне теста в позицию шаблонного текста с сохранением исходной.

```
public static void ChengePattern(Paragraphs paragraphs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("fileName.docx"));
    for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
        //System.out.println("-----"+p.getText());
       List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       if (runs != null) {
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                String text = r.getText(0);
                sb.append(r.getText(r.getTextPosition()));
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                if (sb.toString().contains("Name")) {
                    text = sb.toString().replace("Name", paragraphs.subscriber);
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                }
                else if (sb.toString().contains("Address")) {
                    text = sb.toString().replace("Address", paragraphs.address);
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                }

        }
    }
    doc.write(new FileOutputStream("path\\output.docx"));

}
```

}

Для понятности приведу примеры

```
System.out.println(System.out.println("-----"+p.getText());
```

результат

> ---
>
> -----Приложение №1 к ТУ №
>   -----Т Е Х Н И Ч Е С К И Е   Т Р Е Б О В А Н И Я 
>   -----на присоединение эл.установок 0,4 кВ
>   -----трехэтажного административного комплекса
>   -----Выданы: Name.
>   -----Место расположения объекта: Address.

```
if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    System.out.println("------"+text);
```

> > ------null
> >     ------Приложение №1
> >     ------ к ТУ №
> >
> > ### ------Т Е Х Н И Ч Е С К И Е   Т
>
> ### ------Р
>
> ### ------Е
>
> ### ------Б
>
> ### ------О
>
> ### ------В
>
> ### ------А
>
> ### ------Н
>
> ### ------И
>
> ### ------Я
>
> ------на 
>   ------присоединение 
>   ------эл.установок
>   ------ 0,
>
> ### ------4
>
> ------кВ
>   ------трехэтажн
>   ------ого
>   ------ административн
>   ------ого
>   ------ комплекс
>   ------а

как видно, runs дробит текст в строке параграфа.
и результат лучшего варианта на данный момент

> Приложение №1 к ТУ №
>   Т Е Х Н И Ч Е С К И Е   Т Р Е Б О В А Н И Я 
>   на присоединение эл.установок 0,4 кВ
>   трехэтажного административного комплекса
>   Выданы: NameВыданы:paragraphs.subscriber
>   Место расположения объекта: AddressМесто расположения объекта:paragraphs.address

Вроде бы, можно удалить изначальную строку шаблона и вставить свою, но проблема в том, что не сохраняется форматирование текста, (выделение жирным, шрифты).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615594/replacing-variables-in-a-word-document-template-with-java

Comment: Та же самая проблема, runs разбивает параграф так как ему вздумается

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте обрамить ту часть шаблонного текста, которую надо заменить, спецсимволами, которые более не встречаются в тексте, после чего прогоните все параграфы вот этим

```
private static void glueAllPlaceholderPartsToFirstRun(XWPFParagraph para, char phOpen, char phClose)
    {
        for (int iRun=0; iRun<para.getRuns().size(); ++iRun )
        {
          if (para.getRuns().get(iRun) != null){
            XWPFRun run = para.getRuns().get(iRun);


            int iPos = 0;
            while( run.getText(0) != null && iPos < run.getText(0).length() )
            {
              if( run.getText(0).charAt(iPos) == phOpen )
              {
                int iFin = iPos;
                do
                {
                  ++iFin;
                  if( iFin == run.getText(0).length() )
                  {
                    int iNextRun = iRun;
                    XWPFRun nextRun = null;
                    do
                    {
                      ++iNextRun;
                      if( iNextRun < para.getRuns().size() )
                        nextRun = para.getRuns().get(iNextRun);
                      else
                        nextRun = null;
                    }
                    while( nextRun != null
                           & ( nextRun.getText(0) == null
                             || nextRun.getText(0).length() == 0 ) );
                    if( nextRun != null )
                    {
                      run.setText( run.getText(0) + nextRun.getText(0).charAt(0), 0 );
                      nextRun.setText( nextRun.getText(0).substring(1), 0 );
                    }
                  }
                }
                while( iFin < run.getText(0).length()
                  & run.getText(0).charAt(iFin) != phClose
                  & iFin - iPos < 100 );
                iPos = iFin;
              }
              ++iPos;
            }
          }
        }
    }
```